# Directory is not formed when i run my java code on AWS Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda

When i run my code on eclipse it is running with no error , but when i run my code on AWS Lambda , error is coming at line file.createNewFile() and when i check i found that file.mkdir() is not working i.e.., directory don't exist.The code is :-

```
public Resource get(String id) throws StorageException, StorageFileNotFoundException {
        Resource resource = null;
        File file = null;
        try {
            FileDetails fileDetails = fileStoreDAO.get(id);
            System.out.println(fileDetails.getName());
            if(fileDetails != null) {
                String tempDir = storageProperties.getLocation();
                file = new File(tempDir + File.separator + fileDetails.getName());
                file.mkdir();

                    if(file.exists()) {
                    //p1: delete any file if existent in the directory;
                    file.delete();
                }
                file.createNewFile();
                FileCopyUtils.copy(fileDetails.getFileBytes(), file);
//              System.out.println("filecopyutil  ke agli line me aa gya");
                resource = new UrlResource(Paths.get(tempDir).resolve(fileDetails.getName()).toUri());
                System.out.println("last me");
            } else {
                throw new  StorageFileNotFoundException("No document found with id: " + id);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            if (e instanceof StorageFileNotFoundException) {
                throw (StorageFileNotFoundException) e;
            } else {
                throw new StorageException("", e);
            }
        }
        return resource;
    }
```

and the Storage properties file is :-

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("storage")
public class StorageProperties {

    private String location = "tmp";

    private int maxDocSizeInBytes = 4194304;

    /**
     * Temporary Folder location for storing files
     */
    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
```

Running fine locally , but error when running in AWS Lambda.

Comment: change "tmp" to "/tmp"

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs in a **read-only filesystem** inside `/var/task` when you use Lambda.

If you need to save temporary files you should write it in `/tmp` partition.